# Javascript load more from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

How i can create "load more items" javascript code? I would like load information from the page.php?item=14 file.

I need to update this code with loading from page.php?item=14 file.

Something looks like this:

```
$('.loler:gt(9)').hide().last().after(
     $('#loadmore').click(function(){
        var a = this;
        $('.loler:not(:visible):lt(10)').fadeIn(function(){
         if ($('.loler:not(:visible)').length == 0) $(a).remove();   
        }); return false;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but usually a "Load More" type interface is done by issuing an ajax call to your server and when the results come back, you insert new items into the page based on those results.